# QT using public slot of another class

Tags: qt, signals-slots

I have a class `ArrayToolBar` which has a public member `commandBox` and a public function `createArray()`.

```
class ArrayToolBar : public QToolBar
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit ArrayToolBar(const QString &title, QWidget *parent);
    CommandBox* commandBox = new CommandBox(); 
    void createArray();
```

Here is how `createArray()` is defined

```
void ArrayToolBar::createArray(){
    commandBox->setFocus();
    connect(commandBox, SIGNAL(returnPressed()), this, SLOT(commandBox->SubmitCommand()));
}
```

> SubmitCommand() is a public slot in `CommandBox` class.

My problem is that I am getting an error : No such slot exists.
Is this because I have used a slot of some other class in `ArrayToolBar`? Is there a way around?

Comment: connect(commandBox, &CommandBox::returnPressed, this, [=]() {commandBox->SubmitCommand();});

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Could you please provide a link to documentation, etc. where I can read about how this worked, especially the syntax: [=]().

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda

Comment: @SunitGautam i'll write answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use new connection syntax with labmda expressions.

Qt has a good aricle about it. https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax

And final code will looks like this:

```
connect(commandBox, &CommandBox::returnPressed,
        this, [=] () {commandBox->SubmitCommand();});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use lambda expressions like already mentioned.

But this should do what you want without lambda:

```
connect(commandBox, SIGNAL(returnPressed()), commandBox, SLOT(SubmitCommand()))
```